# Link datatable field when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

**Update**

Here are the code for desktop mode.

```
var boxes = $('.xbSelectRow:checked'); // Looking for checked checkbox

boxes.each(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var balance_amount = row.find(".outstd_amount");
    balance_amount.text(0);
});
```

I just realized that when updating the fields in datatable in desktop mode will be different than mobile mode, it just couldn't link it smartly.

In desktop mode all columns can be seen, so I just use `.find('.outstd_amount')` but in mobile mode this code definitely not going to work. Here you can see the datatable expanded a new row when in mobile mode.

How do I actually update the class `outstd_amount` when it is in mobile mode?

[image]

Comment: It could help if you start us with your desktop code.

Comment: Not sure what UI this is but what does the `Actions` edit button (pencil and paper icon) do?

Comment: question updated with sample code

Comment: @fjoe It will open a modal with more features e.g. delete, view history etc

Comment: You can get row data instead like `var data = table.row( row ).data();` . It will work for both desktop and mobile. It will return an array containing data on the basis of index of `td`. [**https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/yqjnbyxy/**](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/yqjnbyxy/)

Comment: @mmushtaq Thanks for retrieving the field. How about update the field?

Comment: [**https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/rhLmaud4/**](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/rhLmaud4/) => Update cell value of row.

Comment: Ok got it working. You should make an answer then I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm real unsure... Since I did not see your markup and based my answer on a printscreen.

But it should put you on the right track anyway. The trick is to check if the `td` for balance_amount is visible or not. If hidden, then look for the `span` where the value should be.

```
var boxes = $('.xbSelectRow:checked'); // Looking for checked checkbox

boxes.each(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var balance_amount = row.find(".outstd_amount");

    // If the "desktop" td for balance_amount is hidden get the mobile span
    if(!balance_amount.is(":visible"){
      balance_amount = row.next("tr.child").find("span.dtr-data");
    }

    balance_amount.text(0);
});
```